# Who is Ludovico Bourbon?

Tags: royalty

On the cover of the [Paris edition of Raymund Martin's *Pugio Fidei*](http://books.google.com/books?id=euQ3WzJrJXEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), it states,

> "AD SERENISSIMUM REGIÆ STIRPIS PRIMUM PRINCIPEM LUDOVICUM BORBONIUM CONDÆUM BURDEGALÆ ET AQUITANIÆ PROREGEM OPTATISSIMUM."

(My apology for the caps, but that is how it is actually written on the cover, and so, it is how I copied it into a Word .doc I am using for translating the Pugio.)

My question is, who is this individual "Ludovicum Borbonium"? My guess is that, in English, we would say it as "Ludovico Bourbon." I did an exhaustive search of the Bourbon family, but I cannot find anyone who lived during that time (17th century) with the name Ludovico Bourbon. He appears to be a "premier prince" (*princeps primus*), perhaps referring to the title *premier prince du sang royal*. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Ludovic is just the Latin form of the name Louis.

Comment: Excellent! Well, that makes things much easier because I did see many Louis Bourbons. Thank you very much Felix!